# How to eliminate android app header?

Tags: android

How to remove android app header , I want to remove this part , or 
how to work with this part , Can I add some button or some image for this part ?

is there any way to do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

in manifest file

Comment: Can I add some button or some image ?

Comment: yes for that you have to make custom header  http://www.lightrains.com/blog/creating-custom-window-title-android

Comment: can you plz upvote this

Comment: I did am waiting for timer and I will accept this just wait 
thank you again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45534/discussion-between-digvesh-patel-and-shanaz-k)

Answer (score 1):

Use `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` in your theme if you want to remove the title bar from all `Activity`

or

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` if you want to remove the title bar from just one `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

That is an [action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). To hide the action bar, set the theme attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml file for that particular activity - on which you want to disable the action bar. And yes, you can have buttons in the action bar.

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by manifest

```
<activity
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

or if you want to get it done by Activity, use this code in side the `onCreate` Method,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

in Activity before `setContentView`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```